# Separate a python list into multiple lists by threshold?

Tags: python, algorithm

Let's say I have a list of values, where the values are grouped together.
for example,

```
lst = [5.0, 5.2, 4.0, 4.1, 4.05, 5.1]
```

How could I split this into it's two groups, so that the output is `[5.0, 5.2, 5.1], [4.0, 4.05, 4.1]`? I'm sure that every value in each group is within 0.2 of it's partners. What would be the optimal way to assign a threshold for this separation?

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
unique_values = []
    for x in range(len(lst)):
        isInList=False
        for y in range(len(unique_values)):
            if compare_threshold(lst[x], unique_values[y]): #returns true if the two values are within the threshold
                isInList=True
        if isInList == False:
            unique_values.append(lst[x])
    print(unique_values)
```

This gives me a list of single unique points in the list.

```
[55.02123905, 55.02167612, ... 137.0536191, 137.0536604] (118 values)
```

Output:

```
[55.02123905, 57.03325912, 67.0292289, 69.0339192, 71.01344708, 92.02611874, 94.04178177, 109.054014, 112.0537901, 119.0396714, 120.0424827, 136.0683814, 137.0527245]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also what is the group, cut-off rounding to int?

Comment: What do you mean by "What would be the optimal way to assign a threshold for this separation?"? Is 0.2 the threshold for comparing 2 consecutive entries?

Answer (score 1):

Groups have maximum size 0.2.
Needed _entier to get around float precision issues.

```
In [183]: def grouper(x, delta=0.2, _entier=1e-6):
     ...:     out, part = [], []
     ...:     for item in sorted(x):
     ...:         if not part:
     ...:             part = [item]
     ...:         elif item - part[0] <= delta + _entier:
     ...:             part.append(item)
     ...:         else:
     ...:             out.append(part)
     ...:             part = [item]
     ...:     if part:
     ...:         out.append(part)
     ...:     return out

In [184]: grouper(lst)
Out[184]: [[4.0, 4.05, 4.1], [5.0, 5.1, 5.2]]
```

Comment: @kaya3: Sorry, I had copied a previous development version. The right one is their now.

Comment: ote thatwith a list of 5.0, 5.1, 5.3, and 5.2, this would produce [[5.0, 5.1, 5.2], [5.3]]. Some might argue that it would be best to put the 5.2 and 5.3 together, I.e. use a rule of grouping if less than 0.2. It only affects the grouping of items exactly 0.2 out as a corner case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
def grouper(list_, threshold):
    list_.sort()
    prev = None
    group = []
    for item in list_:
        if not prev or item - prev <= threshold:
            group.append(item)
        else:
            yield group
            group = [item]
        prev = item
    if group:
        yield group

lst = [5.0, 5.2, 4.0, 4.1, 4.05, 5.1]
output = list(grouper(lst, threshold=0.2))
```

**Output** :

```
[[4.0, 4.05, 4.1], [5.0, 5.1, 5.2]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am still a student and rushed to post my question before showing what I tried.

Comment: Note that this only ensures that the item is within 0.2 of the previous item in the same list - i.e. the previous partner, not all of its partners.

Comment: @kaya3 I guess then some clustering algorithm would be the best suitable for op.